# Drupal 7: calling custom content type field into page tpl

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm working on a Drupal 7 website. I need custom layout for some pages. so I created page--customContentTypeName.tpl.php file and it addresses perfectly.

The problem is, I need to display some fields in page tpl. The code below works fine in node tpl, but page tpl :/

```
<?php print $content['field_images']['#items']['0']['filename']; ?>" />
```

How can I call custom fields into page tpl?

Appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!!

---

** **SORTED** **

with custom field editing... here is the tutorial video: http://lin-clark.com/blog/intro-drupal-7-theming-fields-and-nodes-templates#comment-54

Answer (score 2):

The structure changed in 7, the field is keyed by language first ("und" by default which means "undefined"), then you can follow this example:

```
// Array of Image values
$images = $node->field_images['und'];

//If you don't know the language, the value is stored in:
$node->language


// First image
$image = $images[0];



// If you need informations about the file itself (e.g. image resolution):
image_get_info( $image["filename"] );


// If you want to access the image, use the URI instead of the filename !
$public_filename = file_create_url( $image["uri"] );


// Either output the IMG tag directly,
$html = '<img src="'.$public_filename.'"/>';

// either use the built-in theme function.
$html = theme(
    "image",
    array(
        "path" => $public_filename,
        "title" => $image["title"]
    )
);
```

Note the usage of the `uri` instead of the `filename` for embedding the image in a page because the [File API in Drupal 7 is more abstracted](http://www.randyfay.com/node/73) (to make it easier to integrate with CDN services).

Comment: Also note that in teaser mode (e.g. a taxonomy term page that lists many nodes), such fields are not provided in variable $node by default.

Comment: By the way, the Drupal-specialized area of StackOverflow will open to public beta in a few days: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

For page.tpl.php
if you access the node directly you can use $node variable

```
$node['field_images']['und'][0]['filename']
```

else use $page variable.

```
$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][1]['field_images']['#items'][0]['filename'];
```

but remember in a page variable you might have more than one node.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 useful modules in drupal for theme developers:
Devel and Theme_developer
Devel module provides a function called dsm() .
using dsm you can recognize that how elements are stored in different objects.
like nodes or ...
for example you can use this statement : dsm($node)
the structure of any nodes in the page will show up in the message box. 
you can type the statements in your codes.